# Text-overlay over an img on hover

Tags: html, css

So far I have created a `container` class which contains an `img` element and a `div` element, which contains text. My aim is to have a image which becomes pale and some text appears on top when the user hovers over the image.

The example bellow is working, but if the user hovers over the `div`, which contains the text, the `div` will disappear. Any suggestions how I can disable this behavior?

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
}

#center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 18px;
}

#overlayImg {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 4s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}

#overlayImg:hover {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

#center{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 4s; /* Safari */
    transition: all 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}

#overlayImg:hover + #center {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">

    <img id="overlayImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/FuBK_testcard_vectorized.svg/768px-FuBK_testcard_vectorized.svg.png" alt="Norway" max-width="100px" max-height="100px">

    <div id="center" class="center"><h1>test test test<h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You options are absolute positioning or negative margins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `pointer-events: none` to the `div`

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}
#center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 18px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#overlayImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 4s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
#overlayImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
#center {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: all 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
#overlayImg:hover + #center {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">

  <img id="overlayImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/FuBK_testcard_vectorized.svg/768px-FuBK_testcard_vectorized.svg.png" alt="Norway">

  <div id="center" class="center">
    <h1>test test test</h1>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

or update the `:hover` rules like this

```
#container:hover #overlayImg {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
#container:hover #center {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}
#center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 18px;
}
#overlayImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 4s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
#center {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: all 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
#container:hover #overlayImg {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
#container:hover #center {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">

  <img id="overlayImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/FuBK_testcard_vectorized.svg/768px-FuBK_testcard_vectorized.svg.png" alt="Norway">

  <div id="center" class="center">
    <h1>test test test</h1>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Side note:

The images `max-width="100px" max-height="100px"` won't work like that, they either should be like this, inline,

```
style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px"
```

or external, in the CSS (recommended)

```
#overlayImg {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 4s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```